# Calculating the following MLE

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Q. A biased die favours the number 2. It's rolled 4 times and 2 comes up twice. It's rolled again 4 times and 2 comes up once. Calculate the Likelihood and find the MLE.

My working out:

$L(\theta;x) = \binom{8}{3}\theta^3(1-\theta)^5$, then taking the first derivative to find the local maximum $\binom{8}{3}\theta^2(1-\theta)^4(3(1-\theta) - 5\theta)=0 \implies \theta = \frac{3}{8}$ we take the second derivative to check the turning points. $\frac{\partial L(\theta;x)}{\partial \theta}=2\binom{8}{3}\theta(1-\theta)^3(32\theta^2-25\theta+3)$ plugging in for $\theta = \frac{3}{8}$ we finally get $2 \cdot 56 \cdot 3/8 \cdot (2/8)^3(32 \cdot (3/8)^3-25\cdot 3/8 + 3) = -2.06$ therefore, $\theta = \frac{3}{8}$ is a global maximum. Have i derived the MLE correctly?

Comment: Editing the question in this way after getting an answer can cause confusion. Anyway, if you have any further question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivative is correct. If we exclude the values $\theta=0$ and $\theta=1$ the equation is

$$3(1-\theta) - 5\theta=0$$

$$3-3\theta - 5\theta=0$$

$$3=8\theta \Rightarrow\theta=\frac38$$

Finally you can evaluate if it is a (local) minimum or (local) maximum. The second derivative is $2 \theta(28 \theta^2 - 21 \theta + 3) (1 - \theta)^3$

Comment: Thanks for double checking! I have updated my answer as I made the mistake of getting $\theta = \frac{3}{5}$ as I had worked out two similar ones. I'll do the second derivative again to see if I get your answer.

Comment: You have made a mistake with the second derivative, it should be $112\theta$

Comment: You can check by yourself what the second derivative is, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5E2%281-x%29%5E4%283%281-x%29+-+5x%29%29%27). I have used the product rule to find the derivative of $\theta^2(1-\theta)^4(3 - 8\theta)$: $$(u\cdot v\cdot w)'=u'\cdot v\cdot w+u\cdot v'\cdot w+u\cdot v\cdot w'$$

Comment: Ah okay, you were missing $\binom{8}{3}$ which is 56 making it 112. Your calculation is correct

Comment: @dollarbill Ah yes. But this is a positive constant. It doesn´t change the sign. So it can be omitted in this case. If $f(x)$ is positive (negative) then $c\cdot f(x)$ is positive (negative) as well, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant ($c\neq 0$).

Comment: Thanks for sharing! my notes mentioned something similar when plotting MLE that I did not have to include the constant. I didn't understand this until now

Comment: @dollarbill It pleases me, that this matter is clear now.

Comment: I have one final question, in this case - what does $\theta$ belong to in terms of intervals. I know that the maximum value $\theta$ can take is $\frac{1}{6^8}$ as that's the probability given 8 rolls. Therefore, do I say $\theta \in  (0, \frac{1}{6^8}]$? Perhaps, I have this wrong.

Comment: @dollarbill If $x$ is the number of 2's in 8 rolls, then the mle is $\theta=\frac{x}8$, where $x\in\{0,1,...,8\}$. So the range of mle is $...$ ? I hope my interpretation of the question is right. As far as I understand $\theta$ is the mle for $p$ and not the overall probability.